# How can msg.sender call a payable function with set price from another contract?

Tags: solidity, payable, import, receive

hello everyone and happy '23.

I'm having issues sorting out the following system.

Contract TipWallet: receives tips with a takeTip() and updates the tip +1 every time it receives one.

Contract Tipper: there is a tipper() function that first calls takeTip() in TipWallet, and if payment is successful, more logic is executed.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;


contract TipWallet {

    
    // the wallet sets the tip
    uint public tip; 
    uint public balance;

    constructor (uint _tip) {
        tip = _tip;
    }

    function payTip() public payable {
        uint _tip = getTip();
        require(_tip == msg.value, "no right tip");
        (bool sent, ) = address(this).call{value: _tip} ("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send ether");
        balance += msg.value;
        // Update the tip
        tip += 1;
    }

    function getTip() public view returns(uint) {
        return tip;
    }
}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "./TipWallet.sol";

contract Tipper {

    TipWallet wallet;
    address[] public buyers;

    constructor(address payable _walletContract) {
        wallet = TipWallet(_walletContract);
    }

    function buy() public payable {
        // pay the tip to the wallet
        wallet.payTip();
        buyers.push(msg.sender);

    }


}
```

PROBLEMs I'M ENCOUNTERING

- Contract Tipper gets the msg.value, not Tipwallet
- OR the takeTip() reverts because there's no tip inside

any tip helps. thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, updated (I tried so many variations that I didn't know what to put as example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1 . `contract TipWallet`:  the below code is not necessary at all, you can delete it. Sending value to the contract itself (address this) require the contract having `receive payable` or `fallback payable` function. This does no effect except making your contract always throwing revert

```
    (bool sent, ) = address(this).call{value: _tip} ("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send ether");
```

2. `contract Tipper`: you need to send `msg.value` along with the function call so the `wallet` contract can receive it:

```
   // pay the tip to the wallet
   wallet.payTip{value: msg.value }();
```

---

The full fixed contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
contract TipWallet {
    // the wallet sets the tip
    uint public tip; 
    uint public balance;

    constructor (uint _tip) {
        tip = _tip;
    }

    function payTip() public payable {
        uint _tip = getTip();
        require(_tip == msg.value, "no right tip");
        balance += msg.value;
        // Update the tip
        tip += 1;
    }

    function getTip() public view returns(uint) {
        return tip;
    }
}

contract Tipper {

    TipWallet wallet;
    address[] public buyers;

    constructor(address payable _walletContract) {
        wallet = TipWallet(_walletContract);
    }
    function buy() public payable {
        // pay the tip to the wallet
        wallet.payTip{value: msg.value}();
        buyers.push(msg.sender);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked. 
just a small add for whom might follow: in the buy() function in Tipper, make sure to:

TipWallet(wallet).payTip{value: msg.value}();

enjoy the weekend :)